How to count only visible values with COUNTIFS and with multiple criteria
I am trying to count number of visible cells that contains a particular text 'ABC' (in $B$2:$B$3484) and satisfies certain condition (5<X<10)
I have tried
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$3484,"ABC",$P$2:$P$3484,">5",$P$2:$P$3484,"<10")

which returns inaccurate values

You will need SUBTOTAL() function here. Read CountIf With Filtered Data

The logic remains same, it doesn't matter whether you have one column or multiple columns. COUNTIF() or COUNTIFS() certainly not the right function. but using SUMPRODUCT() with SUBTOTAL() --> =SUM(N((MAP($B$2:$B$3484,LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(103,x)))*($B$2:$B$3484="ABC")*($P$2:$P$3484>5)*($P$2:$P$3484<10))>0))

Thank you. I have tried implementing, but keep getting the #N/A output. Please any idea why this is?

Have you tried to evaluate the formula why you are getting #N/A?
